# Microdata array of blogPosting

Tags: blogs, schema.org, microdata

I added Microdata to my blog list and I'm not sure of the good relationship (item in red) between each BlogPosting:

[image]

Here is my code:

```
<ul itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Blog">
    <li itemprop="blogPost" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/BlogPosting">
        <!-- first post with my title, image, content .. -->
    </li>
    <li itemprop="blogPost" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/BlogPosting">
        <!-- second post with my title, image, content .. -->
    </li>
</ul>
```

Did I make a mistake?

Comment: What do you mean with "item in red"?

Comment: Oh i'm sorry, i've forgot this pics : http://img15.hostingpics.net/pics/223870test.jpg :(

Comment: I added the image to your question. Are you using exactly the same markup for the other `li` elements in this list? (ideally, [edit] the code in your question and show an example with two `li` elements) Which tool are you using in the screenshot?

Comment: Hi Unor, thank for edit ! I use the plugin "Microdata.reveal" (chrome). And, i'm using exactly the same markup for the other li elements in my list :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your Microdata markup is correct and you are using the Schema.org vocabulary correctly, too.

The parser you are using (Microdata.reveal) seems to be bugged: The `Blog` item should have two `BlogPosting` values for the `blogPost` property: "Item 1" and "Item 2".

[Google’s Structured Data Testing Tool](http://www.google.com/webmasters/tools/richsnippets) is parsing your code correctly:

> [image: The blogPost property references two items: Item 1 and Item 2]

Comment: Thank you very much Unor ! I'll test with your link now :)